# Html5 Canvas Moving Lines

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Hello I am attempting to create a road with gradually growing dashed lines. If you check out my fiddle you will see that the dashed lines are catching up to each other, my math skills aren't very good. I could use some assistance. I understand that the dashed lines are all growing at the same time and their distance between each other must grow as well. (Not sure how to accomplish this)

I believe my issues lie within my Line function

```
      let speed = 1;

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;

      this.update = lines => {
          //Move points over time

          this.y1 += speed;
          this.y2 += speed + 0.3;
          if(this.y2 >= 600){
              this.y2 += speed * 0.30;
              this.draw();
          }else if(this.y2 >= 700){
            this.y1 += speed / 0.40;
            this.draw();
          }else if(this.y2 >= 900){
            this.y2 += speed * 0.55;
            this.draw();
          }
          this.draw();
          console.log(lines[0].y2);
      }  this.draw = () => {
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(innerWidth/4, innerHeight);
        c.lineTo(innerWidth/2, 400);
        c.lineTo(innerWidth/1.333,innerHeight);
        c.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        c.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
        c.strokeStyle="#b97de9";
        c.stroke();
      }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjuc01ck/9/

Comment: are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vRXPxo

Comment: @NagaSaiA Thats actually what i started off making but I want the dashed lines to grow as they re falling down. To give you that feeling that you're driving down a road.

Comment: use ctx.lineWidth, but subdivide each line segment to get a more 3d effect.